# SSRS-2008 interactive sort current sort column

Tags: ssrs-2008

VS2010 - SSRS 2008

While using InterActive Sort I need for the hosting web Page (.aspx) to know on what field/column the report is currently sorted.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks

David